# JDBC - maximum allowable cursors - how do I see my open statements?

Tags: java, jdbc

I've got some resource leaking and I'm trying to find what's causing them. I think I have some statements or resultsets that aren't being closed properly. Is there any way to see all of the cursors that my JDBC connection currently has open? I am using Eclipse.

Comment: Do you think it might depend on the database type you're connecting to?